# php mysql get the value from drop down list print to screen

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Im trying to get the value from a drop down list within a form and print this value to screen. From a form action set to "itself". using this variable in a mysql statement

```
//load drop downs
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM actor_id");

//loads actor_name to drop down
print("<select name=\"actor_name\">\n");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        print ("<option value=" . $row[0] . ">" . $row[1] . "</option>");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}
print("</select>");
//close DB
mysqli_close($db);

?>
<form method = "post" action="actors.php" >

    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" >
</form>

//after submit reloads this
if(isset($_POST['actor_name']))
    {
                    $star = $_POST['actor_name'];
        print "Star: " . $star;     
    }//want to use this variable in a mysql statement
```

Comment: just dose not pass the selected value from the drop down list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to show the `POST` actor is selected in the `drop down list` for this try,

You must `add actor list` in `form element` like

```
<form method = "post" action="actors.php" >
    <?php
    print("<select name=\"actor_name\">\n");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $sel='';
        if($row[0]==$_POST['actor_name'])
           $sel='selected="selected"';
        print ("<option value=" . $row[0] . " ".$sel.">" . $row[1] . "</option>");
        //$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); remove this line it has no meaning
    }
    print("</select>");
    ?>
    ..........
```